# Use Output from one file to delete or outcomment lines in another file using sed / awk

Tags: awk, sed

So i have a gigantic file (file1) where i need to delete or outcomment specific lines, this file could look something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum **abc** dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Cras finibus **123** laoreet dignissim. 
Curabitur dignissim auctor tortor a cursus. 
Nullam sapien ante, tempor eu rutrum
...
```

for this i have file2 which contains strings which i need to locate lines in file1

file2 could look like this:

```
abc
123
xyz
098
...
```

Now, when a string from file2 is found, the line, in file1, where it is found + the line directly beneath it, should be outcommented or deleted. 
so that if **123** is found in the above example, it should delete these two lines (marked with --> ):

```
Lorem ipsum abc dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
--> Cras finibus 123 laoreet dignissim.
--> Curabitur dignissim auctor tortor a cursus.
Nullam sapien ante, tempor eu rutrum
...
```

I hope this makes sense

I was fiddeling around with sed and awk, but never got it to work

Comment: If you have already tried something, it's good to show your attempt.

Comment: I guess the first line ("Lorem ipsum **abc**...") should be also deleted.

Comment: what if a word to found is on a second line  (so deleted by action due to word find in first line) ?

Comment: @ fedorqui - indeed, if one were to take the output from file2, it should.

Comment: @ NeronLeVelu i did not think of that, i dont think it will be an issue however, as the word/string from file2 is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}p{p=0;next}{for(i in a)if(p = $0 ~ i)next}1' file2 file1
```

Populate the array `a` with the lines in `file2`. The first block only applies to `file2` because the total record number `NR` is equal to the record number of the current file `FNR`. `next` skips the rest of the blocks.

For each line of `file1`, loop through the keys in array `a`. If the current line matches the key, skip the line in the output. Also assign `p` the true value. For lines where `p` is true, set it back to false but skip the line in the output. The `1` at the end is always true, so any line that has made it this far is printed, as the default action is to print the line.

Comment: What is the point of `P` and the `next` in the first statement ? Get the same output for `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]};{for(i in a)if($0~i)next}1' file2 file1`. If you wanted to skip two line you should put the `p{p=0;next}` at the start as you set p in the `if(p = $0 ~ i)` before it :)

Comment: @Jidder thanks, I've switched those two blocks round.

Comment: I tried this on a sample, and it seemed to do as intented - no hiccups.
Will make a copy on the existing fle and try it out there, then do a sanity check. 
Thanx

Comment: @ToKeLu good to hear that it's working for you. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/&/{N;d}|' file2 | sed -f - file1 >file3
```

Create a sed script from file2 and run it against file1 saving the results in file3.